# CodeIgniter and Progress bar

Tags: codeigniter, progress-bar

I have several methods in my models, which are called by my controller.  On the client, I want to update a progress bar while the model methods are running.

How can I communicate with the controller to get its progress?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.... But I don't have any clue what you are asking. Could you please clarify what you are asking?

Comment: I think he wants a progress bar on the client to be updated while the controller is running.

Comment: How to implement progressBar that it displays a real job application?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the translation, I do not know English

Comment: maybe it can be done by writing `<script>` tag in controller which update the progressbar

Answer (score 4):

True that you need AJAX / long polling to make this work. Here is XMLHttpRequest2. And to me, this has taken the web to next level. Its time for us to use it. I ve used it with jquery. Probably a lot more easy to understand what I ve done. Might need a little tweak to make it work. Here it goes..

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST/GET',
url: "link/to/controller/method",
data: {whatever = 'foo'},
beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest)
{
  //Upload progress
  XMLHttpRequest.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
     var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
     $( ".jquery-uploadbar-selector" ).progressbar({ value: percentComplete }); //jquery progress bar for upload
    //incase you wanted an upload bar
   }
 }, false); 
 //Download progress
 XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
   if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
     var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
     $( ".jquery-downloadbar-selector" ).progressbar({ value: percentComplete });
   //jquery progress bar for download or in other words The real answer for question
   }
 }, false); 
},
success: function(data){
  //Here goes the end of what you have done.. I would just type.. 
  console.log('Yay!! I guess, I ve answered my first bounty question and hoping to see it work well.');
 }
});
```

Hope it works.. let me know if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using PHP since PHP is server side and when it has completed its work the result is sent to the browser.

You may use Javascript to make AJAX call (google this, it is a way to make call to the server without reloading the page) and each time a method of the model is completed you may add 'loading' to your progress bar using JS. but really in PHP there isn't a way to know how much of an action has been completed

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this with file uploads via Apache and NGINX, however that won't apply to your situation.

One way of doing it would be to use AJAX long polling to monitor a special controller or method of your controller to look for updates and update on the frontend when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. have http connection open with client(user) and when you start the job send data(isWaiting=1) to your client or do ajax polling as Asiq said and fetch isWaiting status.
2. on html client side page , javascript to load progress bar when isWaiting=1
3. html page having this inside body tag

> ```
> <div class="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
> ```

and css

> .overlay { width:100%; height:100%; z-index:5000; left:0;/*IE*/ top:0;  
>               text-align:center; position:fixed;
>               background:       url('https://memberschemes.rics.org/MembersPortal/images/ajax_loader-2.gif') no-repeat fixed center center;
>               background-color: #EFEFEF;
>               opacity:0.7;
>               /*
>               background: #F4F4F4;
>               background-repeat: no-repeat;
>               background-position: center;
>               */
>            }